# What does this wavy downward arrow preceding a piano chord mean?

Tags: piano, notation

I started to play this piece today, & I came across this symbol (wavy arrow pointing downwards in treble clef). I have never seen it before in any piece, nor did I read about it in music theory so far. What does it mean?

[image]

*I am assuming it could mean to play the notes of the chord like an arpeggio, but instead of starting from the lowest note, you start from the highest note (i.e. G in the 5th space), then play D & G (2nd line).* Is my guess correct?

Comment: That's right, it's a reverse arpeggio. The mark is more common in music for guitar and string instruments.

Comment: @ Kilian Foth: If one will poste your comment as an  answer this question this would  be a "Grace note" ;)

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that @KilianFoth. Something new to learn!

Comment: Hahahaha good one @AlbrechtHügli! 

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The symbol indicates the chord should be played as a descending arpeggio. Standard convention is to go from low to high, so when the composer wants to go the opposite way, it needs to be clarified.

Comment: There's also the similar upward wavy arrow for an arpeggio that must go up. I remember transcribing a video game theme that had arpeggiated piano chords and not all of them were arpeggiated the same way, so I put arrows on all the arpeggio markings.

Comment: Sure, you can go the other way as well, and would actually be especially helpful / clear if the music is constantly changing directions.

Comment: @Dekkadeci  I think (not 100% sure) that the default, if no arrowhead, is to arpeggiate upwards.